# push f5sdk pool node details to Prometheus using python prometheus_client

Tags: python, python-3.x, prometheus

I have f5 pool and node data details in a python dictionary in a loop for more than 10+ pools, I was able to create summary metrics and labels and populate values for one value but not able to do in loop `pool={'pool_name': 'testing-prom-tool','pool_member_name': 'promtest', 'mem_port': '443', 'mem_address': 'xx.xx.xx.xx', 'mem_state': 'down'}`  when i use pool as variable in the following code and it returns values in a loop. this is how I tested and was able to get for one value, but I'm not able to get for a loop. It just gives the end value of the loop. How can I achieve this for values in the loop?

Code:

```
import prometheus_client as prom
import random
import time


pool={'pool_name': 'testing-prom-tool','member_name': 'promtest', 'mem_port': '443', 'mem_address': 'xx.xx.xx.xx', 'mem_state': 'down'}
# Create a metric to track time spent and requests made.
REQUEST_TIME = prom.Summary('request_processing_seconds', 'Time spent processing request')


# Decorate function with metric.
@REQUEST_TIME.time()
def process_request():
    time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #                          name                        documentation                            label names ###  I was able to populate all the keys from the dictionary using the pool.keys())
    f5_prom_test = prom.Summary('f5_test','f5_node_status',('pool_name','member_name','mem_port','mem_address','mem_state'))
    prom.start_http_server(1234)
While True:
   process_request()
        f5_prom_test.labels(pool.get('pool_name'),pool.get('member_name'),pool.get('mem_port'),pool.get('mem_address'),pool.get('mem_state'))
#f5_prom.labels(**pool), this works as well
curl -K http://localhost:1234
f5_test_created{mem_address="xx.xx.xx.xxx",mem_name="test-server",pool_name"=testpool",mem_port="5443",mem_state="down"} 1.658982617711136e+09
```

I used http://localhost in my Prometheus.The YAML file only shows when the URL is up, and the data is not stored in the Prometheus tsdb. How can I keep the data in Prometheus tsdb using /metrics

I figured out my return statement only prints last f5 pool details but not all the details in the f5 load balancer , that makes sense why only one values shows in http://localhost

How can i return dictionary in the script?

```
    def f5poolnode_details():
        poolmember_details = {}
        pools = mgmt.tm.ltm.pools.get_collection()
        for pool in pools:
            for member in pool.members_s.get_collection():
                poolmember_details['pool_name'] = pool.name
                poolmember_details['member_name'] = member.name
                poolmember_details['mem_port'] = member.port
                poolmember_details['mem_address'] = member.address
                poolmember_details['mem_state'] = member.state
                print(poolmember_details)##### this gives all the f5 pool details in LB
                return poolmember_details ########### only gives the last f5 pool details in LB


pool={'pool_name': 'testing-prom-tool','member_name': 'promtest', 'mem_port': '443', 'mem_address': 'xx.xx.xx.xx', 'mem_state': 'down'}
# output
```

yes, my example only shows single load balancer's details, I used nested list instead of single load balancer.

```
import prometheus_client as prom
import random
import time


pool=f5poolnode_details()


# Create a metric to track time spent and requests made.
REQUEST_TIME = prom.Summary('request_processing_seconds', 'Time spent processing request')


# Decorate function with metric.
@REQUEST_TIME.time()
def process_request():
    time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for values in pool:
        f5_prom.labels(values['pool_name'],values['member_name'],values[‘mem_port'],values[‘mem_address'],values[‘mem_state'])

prom.start_http_server(9240)
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

instead of using `values['mem_address']` i want to use dictionary

multiple lb details output for nested list
`[{'pool_name': 'testing-prom-tool1','member_name': 'promtest', 'mem_port': '443', 'mem_address': 'xx.xx.xx.xx', 'mem_state': 'down'}, {'pool_name': 'testing-prom-tool2','member_name': 'promtest', 'mem_port': '443', 'mem_address': 'xx.xx.xx.xx', 'mem_state': 'down'},{'pool_name': 'testing-prom-tool3','member_name': 'promtest', 'mem_port': '443', 'mem_address': 'xx.xx.xx.xx', 'mem_state': 'down'}]`

expected output :

`{'pool_name': 'testing-prom-tool1','member_name': 'promtest', 'mem_port': '443', 'mem_address': 'xx.xx.xx.xx', 'mem_state': 'down'} {'pool_name': 'testing-prom-tool2','member_name': 'promtest', 'mem_port': '443', 'mem_address': 'xx.xx.xx.xx', 'mem_state': 'down'}{'pool_name': 'testing-prom-tool3','member_name': 'promtest', 'mem_port': '443', 'mem_address': 'xx.xx.xx.xx', 'mem_state': 'down'}`

Comment: Your example only shows a single load balancer’s details. That’s what you had already. How can you get all of them if the result is a single item?

Comment: i updated my question with  excepted output

Comment: What you’re showing is a list of dictionaries, but with non-functional syntax. My answer returns the same list with the right syntax.

Comment: Correct, I used your answer to generate that list, before i couldn't even return anything. I was trying to get the details in dictionary not list by using your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I’ve understood correctly, you want a list, but instead you immediately return an object created in the first iteration of the loop. I suggest using a nested list comprehension:

```py
def f5poolnode_details():
    return [
        {
            "pool_name": pool.name,
            "member_name": member.name,
            "mem_port": member.port,
            "mem_address": member.address,
            "mem_state": member.state,
        }
        for member in pool.members_s.get_collection()
        for pool in mgmt.tm.ltm.pools.get_collection()
    ]
```

This will return a list of objects, each of which has the named properties.

Comment: Thanks @Aankhen for responding, i want a dictionary. Let me try using nested dictionary comprehension.

Comment: If you add an example of what the output should be to your question, I can edit the answer.

Comment: excepted output ```pool={'pool_name': 'testing-prom-tool','member_name': 'promtest', 'mem_port': '443', 'mem_address': 'xx.xx.xx.xx', 'mem_state': 'down'}                  ```      nested list output ```[{'pool_name': 'testing-prom-tool','member_name': 'promtest', 'mem_port': '443', 'mem_address': 'xx.xx.xx.xx', 'mem_state': 'down'}] ```

Comment: Sorry, I don’t think I know what it is you want this to do.